# Error with function np.interp and pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ubuntu

Someone can suggest how to correct this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 975, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 982, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0.5702862420640393
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BatchNTC_dev.py", line 83, in <module>
    tau = ignitionDelay(timeHistory.loc[t], T_rise)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1124, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1073, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3739, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 395, in get_loc
    return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
  File "/home/morpheus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0.5702862420640393
```

this is the original script

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import time
import csv
import cantera as ct
print('Running Cantera version: ' + ct.__version__)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 18
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')

gas = ct.Solution('Seiser.cti')

# Define the reactor temperature and pressure
reactor_temperature = 1000  # Kelvin
reactor_pressure = 101325  # Pascals

gas.TP = reactor_temperature, reactor_pressure

# Define the fuel, oxidizer and set the stoichiometry
gas.set_equivalence_ratio(phi=1.0, fuel="nc7h16", oxidizer={"o2": 1.0, "n2": 3.76})

# Create a batch reactor object and add it to a reactor network
# In this example, the batch reactor will be the only reactor
# in the network
r = ct.IdealGasReactor(contents=gas, name="Batch Reactor")
reactor_network = ct.ReactorNet([r])
```

Thank you

```
def ignitionDelay(states, dT):

    """

    This function computes the ignition delay from the occurence of the

    peak in species' concentration.

    """
    idt = np.interp(states.T[0]+dT, states.T, states.t)#

    return idt

T_rise=10.


r = ct.IdealGasReactor(contents=gas, name='Batch Reactor')
reactorNetwork = ct.ReactorNet([r])

# now compile a list of all variables for which we will store data
stateVariableNames = [r.component_name(item) for item in range(r.n_vars)]

# use the above list to create a DataFrame
timeHistory = pd.DataFrame(columns=stateVariableNames)

t0 = time.time()

# This is a starting estimate. If you do not get an ignition within this time, increase it
estimatedIgnitionDelayTime = 0.1
t = 0

counter = 1;
while(t < estimatedIgnitionDelayTime):
    t = reactorNetwork.step()
    if (counter%10 == 0):
        # We will save only every 10th value. Otherwise, this takes too long
        # Note that the species concentrations are mass fractions
        timeHistory.loc[t] = reactorNetwork.get_state()
    counter+=1
    
timeHistory.to_csv("time_historyBATCH.csv")

# We will use the 'oh' species to compute the ignition delay
tau = ignitionDelay(timeHistory.loc[t], T_rise)

#Toc
t1 = time.time()

print('Computed Ignition Delay: {:.3e} seconds. Took {:3.2f}s to compute'.format(tau, t1-t0))

# If you want to save all the data - molefractions, temperature, pressure, etc
```

Comment: What is confusing about the error? `0.5702862420640393` is not a column in the frame `timeHistory`

Comment: Dear @It_is_Chris I modified with timeHistory but I have still an error...it cannot run the function tau

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your code/the desired behavior, the value of t is being incremented during your while loop. The while loop continues until t is greater than estimatedIgnitionDelayTime.

I imagine that means the values in timeHistory contains only values of t that are less than this estimatedIgnitionDelayTime. However, t will be incremented one more time until it is greater than estimatedIgnitionDelayTime, so when you try to access timeHistory.loc[t] this value of t (greater than estimatedIgnitionDelayTime) is not in the index of your timeHistory Dataframe, causing a KeyError.

Try saving the last value of t, or modifying your while loop or dataframe in order to avoid this error

Comment: Dear @C Hawort, timeHistory contains all values of the simulations...in particular I' like to do interp with T[0]+dt, T and t

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely caused by one of two things:

1. `0.5702862420640393` key isn't actually in `timeHistory`. Can't help you there
2. More broadly, a number similar to `0.5702862420640393` was used to insert, but it wasn't able to match, because floating point is messy.

In general, don't use floating point values as keys or indices. If they are natively time-like values you are handling, use a uint value (e.g. `time.time_ns()`), a `datetime.datetime/timedelta`,  and/or use `pandas.to_datetime(val)`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import time
import csv
import cantera as ct
print('Running Cantera version: ' + ct.__version__)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 18
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')

gas = ct.Solution('Seiser.cti')

# Define the reactor temperature and pressure
reactor_temperature = 1000  # Kelvin
reactor_pressure = 101325  # Pascals

gas.TP = reactor_temperature, reactor_pressure

# Define the fuel, oxidizer and set the stoichiometry
gas.set_equivalence_ratio(phi=1.0, fuel="nc7h16", oxidizer={"o2": 1.0, "n2": 3.76})

# Create a batch reactor object and add it to a reactor network
# In this example, the batch reactor will be the only reactor
# in the network
r = ct.IdealGasReactor(contents=gas, name="Batch Reactor")
reactor_network = ct.ReactorNet([r])
 

tHy_extra = ct.SolutionArray(gas, extra="t")

def ignitionDelay(states, dT):

    """

    This function computes the ignition delay from the occurence of the

    peak in species' concentration.

    """
    idt = np.interp(states.T[0]+dT,states.T, states.t)#

    return idt

T_rise=10.


r = ct.IdealGasReactor(contents=gas, name='Batch Reactor')
reactorNetwork = ct.ReactorNet([r])

# now compile a list of all variables for which we will store data
stateVariableNames = [r.component_name(item) for item in range(r.n_vars)]

# use the above list to create a DataFrame
timeHistory = pd.DataFrame(columns=stateVariableNames)
timeHistory.index.name = 'time'

t0 = time.time()

# This is a starting estimate. If you do not get an ignition within this time, increase it
estimatedIgnitionDelayTime = 0.1
t = 0

counter = 1;
while(t < estimatedIgnitionDelayTime):
    t = reactorNetwork.step()
    if (counter%10 == 0):
        # We will save only every 10th value. Otherwise, this takes too long
        # Note that the species concentrations are mass fractions
        timeHistory.loc[t] = reactorNetwork.get_state()
        tHy_extra.append(r.thermo.state, t=t)
    counter+=1
    
 #timeHistory.to_csv("time_historyBATCH.csv")

# We will use the 'oh' species to compute the ignition delay
tau = ignitionDelay(tHy_extra, T_rise)

timeHistory_Full=timeHistory.assign(**{'tau': tau})

timeHistory_Full.to_csv("Finale.csv")
#Toc
t1 = time.time()

print('Computed Ignition Delay: {:.3e} seconds. Took {:3.2f}s to compute'.format(tau, t1-t0))
```